# SELECT from database with fake data is producing a count greater than zero

Tags: php, html, mysql, authentication

im trying to create a login script and I feel like im almost there but for some reason when I test it by typing in incorrect usernames and passwords it still thinks it has got something from the database.

here is my form code:

```
        <form method="post" action="checklogin.php">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label style="color:#6b6a6b;" for="username">Username: </label></td>
                    <td><input class="textbox" type="text" name="username"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="password">Password: </label></td>
                    <td><input class="textbox" type="password" name="password"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value=""></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

and here is my PHP code:

```
session_start();
$con=mysqli_connect("********", "*******", "******", "******");
$myroot = "";
$previousURL = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],PHP_URL_PATH);

if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && $_POST['username'] != "" && $_POST['password'] != ""){
        if (strlen($_POST['username']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['username']) < 4)
        {
            $error = 'Incorrect Length for Username or Password';
        }
        /*** check the password is the correct length ***/
        elseif (strlen($_POST['password']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['password']) < 4)
        {
            $error = 'Incorrect Length for Username or Password';
        }
        /*** check the username has only alpha numeric characters ***/
        elseif (ctype_alnum($_POST['username']) != true)
        {
            /*** if there is no match ***/
            $error = "Username must be alpha numeric";
        }
        /*** check the password has only alpha numeric characters ***/
        elseif (ctype_alnum($_POST['password']) != true)
        {
            /*** if there is no match ***/
            $error = "Password must be alpha numeric";
        }

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $username = stripslashes($username);
        $password = stripslashes($password);
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);
        $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM RAE_customers WHERE username='" . $username . "' AND password='" . $password . "'")  or die(mysqli_error($con));

        $count=count($result);

        if($count==1){

            // Register $username
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            var_dump($_SESSION['username']);
            echo "<br>";
            echo $count;
            /*if($previousURL == "/checkout.php"){
                header('Location: details.php');
            }
            elseif($previousURL == "/login.php"){
                header('location: index.php');
            }*/

        }
        else {
            $error = "Wrong Username or Password.";
        }
        if(isset($error)){
            echo $error;
        }
        else{
            echo "success";
        }
    }
    else{
        $error = "Please enter a Username and Password.";
    }

}
else{
    header('location:index.php');
}
```

When I type in dummy usernames and passwords the It treats it like they are correct.

I get these results

**string(6) "dffddf" 
1success**

does anybody see the problem with my code?

Comment: Are you killing the session anywhere before running this? That could be an artifact from a  test session you have created previously.

Comment: echo the query and paste directly in database sql option

Comment: @timstermatic could you elaborate a little? as far as i know the session should not be created until the user enters a correct username and password. I do have a logout file which I use to destroy the sessions when I want to re-test...(PiLHA) ok I've done that...not different though :(

Comment: @PiLHA sorry I spoke too soon...that did actually work...thankyou very much :)

Comment: The length limitation on your passwords will be the cause of your downfall.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$result` is a mysqli result object so `count($result)` will always give `1` (unless the query fails).

Try using:

```
$result->num_rows;
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use count
count only works on arrays and what you are getting is a mysqli result
instead use mysqli_num_rows
so

```
$count=count($result);
```

becomes

```
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
```